# Erratic memory behavior of Objective-C on x86_64

Tags: objective-c, x86-64, foundation

I came across a weird issue when testing my opensource project [MHTextSearch](https://github.com/matehat/MHTextSearch). At line [169 of MHTextIndex.m](https://github.com/matehat/MHTextSearch/blob/v0.1.0/Classes/MHTextIndex.m#L169):

```
uint64_t maxLength = [indexedString maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:encoding];
// some code

for (...) {

    [indexedString getBytes:keyPtr
                  maxLength:maxLength
                 usedLength:&usedLength
                   encoding:encoding
                    options:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                      range:subRange
             remainingRange:NULL];

    // some more code
}
```

Nothing, anywhere else, modifies `maxLength`. On the second iteration, maxLength is equal to `0`, no matter what its previous value was. If I set a watchpoint on it, I see it changes in `-[NSString getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:]`, at

```
0x100038d19:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdx
0x100038d1d:  movq   %rdx, (%rsi)
0x100038d20:  testq  %rcx, %rcx            << this instruction
```

The very weird thing about this is that it only happens on the x86_64 architecture, and it can be fixed if I change the code like this

```
uint64_t maxLength = [indexedString maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:encoding];
uint64_t strLength = maxLength;
// some code

for (...) {

    [indexedString getBytes:keyPtr
                  maxLength:strLength
                 usedLength:&usedLength
                   encoding:encoding
                    options:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                      range:subRange
             remainingRange:NULL];

    // some more code
}
```

With this code, `maxLength` still gets changed to 0 **at the same instruction**, but `strLength` stays consistent, so the effect is removed.

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usedLength` has the wrong type.  It's declared `uint32_t`.  However, it should be declared `NSUInteger`, which is 32 bits on 32 bit architectures and 64 bits on 64 bit architectures.

Comment: You're right! But still, I don't get understand how that affected the value of maxLength ...

Comment: They are consecutive on the stack. Since  `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:` treats it as 64 bits, it overwrites the 32 bits adjacent to your `usedLength` variable.  That happens to be the low 32 bits of `maxLength`.

Comment: Clear as day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you not get a compiler diagnostic complaining that you passed a value of type uint32_t* to a parameter of type NSInteger* ?